# How do I specify scenario and request names as header values?

Tags: scala, gatling

I want to send scenario and request names as a header value. Is there any specific session variables for that?
I see the scenario name when I println my session. But how can I access it form a string?

Something like this:

```
"TEST_NAME_HEADER" -> "${scenarioName}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write `header("TEST_NAME_HEADER", _.scenario)`.

Because an `Expression[X]` is a function taking a `Session` returning a `Validation[X]`. And there is an implicit conversion from `X` to `Validation[X]`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, look here https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_protocol#http-headers

But, before doing that, you need to declare a variable with the scenario name or, if you don't want to, you can explicit declare the name in the headers.

```
.header("TEST_NAME_HEADER", "my_scenario_name")
```